# Query with DISTINCT returning duplicate results

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I'm attempting to create a label merge in Word using VBA to pull the data via ODBC. However, despite using DISTINCT, I'm getting duplicate values (thus duplicate labels). All fields selected need to be unique, I'm not trying to filter on a single field. I'm pretty green with SQL, what have I missed here? If I open the recipient list in Word, it tells me there are duplicates.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o.NamFullName, e.LocHolderName, e.EADUnitTitle 
FROM ecatalog.csv AS e 
INNER JOIN EADOrigi.csv AS o ON e.ecatalogue_key = o.ecatalogue_key
```

Comment: Most likely you have a whitespoace difference or none printable characters. What is your source database? Can you run the query there?

Comment: Edit your question and show some sample results with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have duplicate rows being returned. You might be able to use a CTE. Example:

```
;WITH catCTE([ecatalogue_key], 
            [LocHolderName], 
            [EADUnitTitle])
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
                [Ecatalogue_key], 
                [LOCHOLDERNAME], 
                [EADUNITTITLE]
         FROM   [ecatalog].[csv]),
     eadCTE([NamFullName])
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
                [ecatalogue_key], 
                [namfullname]
         FROM   [EADOrigi].[csv])
     SELECT [o].[NamFullName], 
            [e].[LocHolderName], 
            [e].[EADUnitTitle]
     FROM   [catCTE] AS [e]
            JOIN [eadCTE] AS [o] ON [e].[ecatalogue_key] = [o].[ecatalogue_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, this seems to have resolved itself and is returning exactly what it should be. I suspect it has more to do with Word and VBA than SQL. Apologies to those who spent time responding.